# Android version issue for answering incoming call

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have code for answering incoming call using Xamarin android. but it does not work in marshmallow.
We tried by using HEADSETHOOK. This single line code is help to auto answer in android version kitkat. The same code is not working on any other versions(higher). It requires MODIFY_PHONE_STATE Permission which are NOT FOR 3rd Apps. I could not go with ROOTING solution. Please suggest me if any other alternate to auto answer an incoming calls.
can any one help me.

Comment: Doesn't work is not proper explanation. What is not working? Do you have any exceptions? Provide more detailed explanation.

Comment: android version is problem. kitkat and lower versions are working good. after kitkat like lolypop,marshmallow versions are not working.